# iTunes Mis-Installed?

Tags: windows-xp, itunes, installation, installer

Recently, I used [Ninite](http://ninite.com/) to install iTunes on my computer (along with a lot of other stuff). Just the iTunes failed to install, although I didn't notice at the time (new hard drive, so I had a lot of other stuff to do). Now, when I try to install it alone with Ninite I get an error "Failed - Invalid attribute - 682", although it works better than the Apple installer, which does absolutely nothing when I open it.

Then, the strangest thing happened when I installed and ran [Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/). It detected that I had an iTunes installation, when I clearly don't have one (nothing in Program Files, nothing in Add/Remove Programs, nothing in Revo Uninstaller). I also searched my registry for 'iTunes' but didn't find anything I'd be confident enough to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because of installer files might be still present on the system.

Following is from apple site:

You can download the Windows Installer Cleanup Utility from Microsoft, which will clean up any leftover installer files that may be causing issues with your current installation. To do this:

1. Click  [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;290301)  first, and read the important information about the software.
2. Click the "Download the Windows Installer Cleanup Utility package now" link on that page to download a file titled msicuu2.exe.
3. Open the msicuu2.exe file and follow the prompts to install it.
4. Choose **Start** >  **All Programs**  and then click  **Windows Install Cleanup**; the Windows Installer Clean Up Utility window appears, listing software that is currently installed on your computer.
5. Select iTunes from the list and click Remove.
6. Click OK in the confirmation dialog that appears.
7. Repeat steps 5 and 6 if you have multiple iTunes entries listed.
8. Select QuickTime from the list and click Remove.
9. Click OK in the confirmation dialog that appears.
10. Repeat steps 8 and 9 if you have multiple QuickTime entries listed.
11. Click Exit.
12. Restart the computer.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1926?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Thanks, it was actually the temp files thing, because WICU didn't find anything (neat tool, though)